# Android is Crashing on ListPreference

Tags: android, android-preferences, listpreference

I am trying to get the value after the it is selected in setting preferences dialog. But I get  a `ClassCastException` and a crash?  Probably because I'm not sure how to get the value that has been selected and save it.  Essentially I need to be able to get the new value in another `Activity`. How do you get these values and save and be able to find them in other activities?

```
 public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

        SharedPreferences s = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", 0);

        // Create a editor to edit the preferences:
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = s.edit();

 if (key.equals("language_key")) {

       sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) sharedPreferences; 
       String entryvalue = (String) listPref.getEntry();

        if (entryvalue == "EN")
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "EN" + entryvalue);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "else" + entryvalue);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }



       }
}
```

preferences xml file

```
<ListPreference 
            android:key="language_key"
            android:summary="Choice of language mode"
            android:title="Language Mode"
            android:defaultValue="CH"
            android:entries="@array/Languages"
        android:entryValues="@array/LanguageValues"   />
```

array.xml

```
<string-array name="Languages">
    <item name="EN">English</item>
    <item name="CH">Chinese</item>
    <item name="SP">Spanish</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="LanguagesValues">
    <item name="EN">EN</item>
    <item name="CH">CH</item>
    <item name="SP">SP</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: sharedPreferences cannot be type casted to ListPreference. You need to use the key to get the value from sharedPreferences like sharedPreferences.get(key,"defaultValue");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sharedPreferences` can't be casted to ListPreferences.
For getting value, invoke `getString` method:

```
sharedPreferences.getString( "language_key", "");
```

Comment: I change to your suggestion but when I select the EN option, it goes to else statement?

Comment: How do I save the value so I can use it in another activity?