# Android - Populate Spinner ArrayAdapter from value specified in Settings ListPreference

Tags: android, android-fragments, settings, android-preferences, listpreference

My code should take the specified value from the listpreference in my settings activity and populate the arrayadapter for my spinner with the specified content.  Currently I am trying to accomplish this in onResume.  My spinner is `spLoadFrom`.  Below is the code:

onResume of my Fragment which displays a Spinner:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getBaseContext());

    Integer values = getPrefs.getInt("prefSections", 1);

    switch (values) {
        case 1:
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, displayName);
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            spLoadFrom.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            SpinnerListener spListener = new SpinnerListener();

            spLoadFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(spListener);
            break;
        case 2:
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, displayName2);
            spinnerArrayAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            spLoadFrom.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter2);
            SpinnerListener spListener2 = new SpinnerListener();

            spLoadFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(spListener2);
            break;
        case 3:
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, displayName3);
            spinnerArrayAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            spLoadFrom.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter3);
            SpinnerListener spListener3 = new SpinnerListener();

            spLoadFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(spListener3);
            break;
        case 4:
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, displayName4);
            spinnerArrayAdapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            spLoadFrom.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter4);
            SpinnerListener spListener4 = new SpinnerListener();

            spLoadFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(spListener4);
            break;
        case 5:
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, displayName5);
            spinnerArrayAdapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            spLoadFrom.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter5);
            SpinnerListener spListener5 = new SpinnerListener();

            spLoadFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(spListener5);
            break;
        default:
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapterd = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, displayName);
            spinnerArrayAdapterd.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            spLoadFrom.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapterd);
            SpinnerListener spListenerd = new SpinnerListener();

            spLoadFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(spListenerd);
    }
}
```

My settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/prefUpdateCat">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="prefUpdate"
        android:summary="On/Off"
        android:title="Check for updates" />
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/prefSectionsCat">
    <ListPreference
        android:key="pref_Sections"
        android:entries="@array/prefSections"
        android:entryValues="@array/prefSectionsValues"
        android:summary="How the 7110.65 should be displayed"
        android:title="7110.65 displayed" />
</PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

My arrays.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string-array name="prefSections">
    <item name="sec">Split by Section</item>
    <item name="secchap">Split by Section with Chapters</item>
    <item name="secchapwhole">Split by Section with Chapters and the entire document</item>
    <item name="chap">Split by Chapters</item>
    <item name="chapwhole">Split by Chapters and the entire document</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="prefSectionsValues">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

Settings Activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

private static final String TAG = "MYAPP";

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(SettingsActivity.this, R.xml.settings, false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Prefs have changed");

}
}
```

How could I properly load the value of the sections that the user selects?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my question after further browsing of StackOverflow, but will keep it up with the answer here in case someone else has this problem.

I had to change my `values` to:

```
Integer values = Integer.parseInt(getPrefs.getString("pref_Sections", ""));
```

instead of having it as:

```
Integer values = getPrefs.getInt("prefSections", 1);
```

I got the idea from looking at the answer posted by `ilsy` at  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314611/android-is-crashing-on-listpreference).

Comment: yup, I was just about to say that your preference key was not matching with your values variable. But also, instead of using ("pref_Sections", "") use ("pref_Sections", -1)

Comment: @mtorres why would you suggest using -1? How would that affect the code/results?